# How to export a file from the Assets folder to the phone's Documents folder in Windows Phone 8.1 RT?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to export a file from the Assets folder to the phone's Documents folder in Windows Phone 8.1 RT using C#. I've enabled documents library capability and able to access Documents Library. But I'm unable to copy a file.

Anyone?

Comment: Also, check out an app called 'Files' makes it easy to search for files on your phone.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried copying a file from Assets, but I can write out a file to my phone's Documents folder ok:

```
var myFolder = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;
var myFile = await myFolder.CreateFileAsync("test.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(myFile, "hello world");
```

Do you have the correct File Type Association in the manifest? Should be something like:

```
<Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
  <FileTypeAssociation Name="txt">
    <DisplayName>txt</DisplayName>
      <SupportedFileTypes>
        <FileType>.txt</FileType>
      </SupportedFileTypes>
  </FileTypeAssociation>
</Extension>
```

Comment: I need to copy. Not to create. Creating is fine. There's no option to Copy in DocumentsLibrary. :/

Comment: What kind of files? Can you read them in byte[] format from Assets Folder, then just write them out to Documents Folder?

Comment: It's a SQlite db file. Can be large in size.

Comment: How large? I'd still try copying the file from Assets to memory, then to Documents Folder. See if it runs outs of memory.

Comment: I did it. Had to use a FileSavePicker. Thank you! :)

Comment: I tried writing a byte array with FileIO. But it failed for some reason.